# c# Interop Word Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I´m trying to write a table with Interop Word, but i want not to allow breaks across pages. So i use Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages property, but it doesn´t work for me, and i don´t know what the problem is ?

any help ?

```
 Word.Table table = rngDoc.Tables.Add(rngDoc, numFilasNueva, numColumnas);
        table.Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = (int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```

Comment: Is the row breaking across pages or the table breaking? Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/94eabc4c-70dc-4a8d-9297-1e70d282f59e/why-does-allowbreakacrosspages-seem-to-have-no-effect?forum=worddev) out

Comment: hi @Magnetron, is the table breaking. thank u !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `AllowBreakAcrossPages` only works on single rows. It can't keep the entire table on one page.

If the table needs to be kept on one page in its entirety it's possible to use Paragraph formatting: `KeepWithNext` (except the last paragraph in the table) and `KeepLinesTogether`. (Perferably with a Style, not direct formatting.)

Or, nest the table in another table (one row, one column = one cell) with `AllowBreakAcrossPages` set to False.

Or put the table in a Frame or TextBox.

These last two will not break to another page, however, if the table is longer than a page.

Answer (score 0):

I did it

```
table.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
table.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
table.Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = (int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
Word.ParagraphFormat pf = table.Range.ParagraphFormat;
pf.KeepWithNext = (int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
pf.KeepTogether = (int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```